# jqgrid full month names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I've tried:

```
$grid->setColProperty("order_time", array( 
    "formatter"=>"date", 
    "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-M-d","newformat"=>"d/M/Y"), 
    "search"=>false 
   ) 
);
```

I got wit this something like: `27/Oct/2011`

I've also tried :

```
"formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-M-d","newformat"=>"d/MM/Y"),
```

But I got something strange... `27/OctOct/2011`

How can i get the date this format : `27/October/2011`

Comment: The docs I found suggest it should be 'm' or 'mm' or maybe even 'F' instead of 'M'.

Comment: omg thanks! didn't see in docs... can u give me a link pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types

> The definition of the date format uses the **PHP conversions.**

So you can look them up here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php